# How to check if current url is top page in laravel blade?

Tags: laravel, if-statement, laravel-blade

I want to change title tag only if current url is top page.
so I wrote on blade:

```
@if (\Request::is('/*'))
<title>You are on the article page</title>
@else
<title>You are on the top page</title>
@endif
```

and several similar way I tried, but didn't work.

[Addtional info]

I'm trying to:

```
https://example.com/ -> top page

https://example.com/?keyword=* ->article page
```

What should I do in this case? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use route name
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#named-routes

Ex:

```
@if (@if(request()->route()->getName()) === 'top')
<title>You are on the top page</title>
@else
<title>You are on the article page</title>
@endif
```

Comment: I tried but didn't work for my situation. I added additional info.

Comment: @Tieria two url are same route. I think you can't do it

Comment: Or you can check query parameter to check page, such as url has keywork will be article page, otherwise will be top page

Comment: OP does not say anything about using named routes?

Comment: I could accomplish with you advice, Nguyen Hung Thai. so I just get `$keyword` from controller and put like  `@if (!empty($keyword))` then It worked. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

The [standard way to check the current URL is](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/urls#accessing-the-current-url):

```
url()->current()
```

From your code though, it looks like you use the query string to display different pages, so all (or at least more than 1) page will have the same URL.  So you'll need to combine that test with a test of the query string.  You can [check the query string with](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests#retrieving-input):

```
$request->query('keyword')
```

which you can access in a view using [the `request()` helper](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-request):

```
request()->query('keyword')
```

So for your title code, you could use something like:

```
@if (url()->current() === '/' && empty(request()->query('keyword'))
    <title>You are on the top page</title>
@elseif (url()->current() === '/' && request()->query('keyword') === 'something')
    <title>You are on the article page</title>
@endif
```